# How can I create a custompin where I am able to add more options beside the Pin.Label, Pin.Adress etc

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to create a custom pin that i add to my map so I can get more options than just the standard ones so I add some more options when I use the pin. I have started with something but I cannot reach the strings I created.

```
    public Pin MyCustomPinHolder
    {

        get {  return MyCustomPinHolder; }
        set { 

         string info1;
         string info2;

        ;}

    }
```

So I can later use the pin like this:

```
    MyCustomPinHolder.Label = "";
    MyCustomPinHolder.Address = "";
```

And beside the standardpin-features such as Label + Address I also want to use the strings that i created, but now I cannot find them (example below):

```
    MyCustomPinHolder.info1 = "";
    MyCustomPinHolder.info2 = "";
```

Comment: If you want to render additional data on the map itself, you would have to write a custom renderer, or a package like TKCustomMap

Comment: i just want to use it to push info to a new page. so not show the actual info on the pin or something like that. is it possible or do i need a renderer for that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyCustomPinHolder
{

     public MyCustomPinHolder() {
       MapPin = new Pin();
     }

     public string info1 { get; set; }
     public string info2 { get; set; }
     public Pin MapPin { get; set; }
 }
```

to use it:

```
var myPin = new MyCustomPinHolder();
myPin.info1 = "foo";
myPin.info2 = "bar";
myPin.MapPin.Label = "blah";
myPin.MapPin.Address = "blah";
myPin.MapPin.Position = new Position(lat, long);

myMap.Pins.Add(myPin.MapPin);
```

in the click handler

```
  public void Pin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Pin p = (Pin) sender;

    // we need to find the custom pin holder that contains this pin
    // assume pins is a List<MyCustomPinHolder> with all of your pins in it
    var holder = pins.First(x => x.MapPin == p);

    // pass the entire MyCustomPinHolder object to the next page
    Navigation.PushModalAsync (new DetailPage(holder)); 

  }
```

Comment: and how to send it to the next page? when I click on the pin now the next page does not recieve the info:      `Pin pin = (Pin)s;
   var myPin = new MyCustomPinHolder();

   Navigation.PushModalAsync (new DetailPage(myPin.MapPin.Address, myPin.MapPin.Label, myPin.info1));`

Comment: error: `var holder = myPins.First(x => x.MapPin == p);` Sequence contains no matching element

Comment: damn, i have alot of code tht needs to adjust with this solution. Maybe it is better to make a solution with a objectID instead? what do u think? I will give u the answer for this solution though of course.

Comment: is myPins a List<MyCustomPinHolder>?    You can also pass the individual properties of holder to DetailPage - there is no reason you have to pass the entire object.